# Does MySQL has function which will return the points inside polygon?

Tags: polygon, mysql

I have MySQL database with polygons, and also the database with points (column longitude and column latitude), is it possible to return all points inside one polygon?

Comment: You say the points have longitude and latitude columns. Do they also have a geometry column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 5.6.1+, take a look at [ST_Contains](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html#function_st-contains.).

Given table called points and polygons, with a primary key called `id` and a geometry column called `geometry`, this should work:

`SELECT points.id FROM polygons, points WHERE ST_CONTAINS(polygons.geom, points.geom);`

If there's no geometry column for the points table, but there are latitude and longitude columns, you can use the MySQL `Point()` function to convert long/lat columns to a point, like this:

`SELECT points.id FROM polygons, points WHERE ST_CONTAINS(polygons.geom, Point(points.longitude, points.latitude));`

Note that MySQL versions prior to 5.6.1 provide a [Contains](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html#function_contains) function which uses the MBR of the polygon, not the actual polygon boundaries, which might also work for you.

Comment: Will this work if the "point" records do not have a geometry column?

Comment: @blah238 - You're right, it won't work without a geom column, but I updated my answer with another approach when points are represented by lat/lng columns.